# SQL Server CLR : how to call WCF Service In CLR SQL stored procedure in database project

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2012, clrstoredprocedure

I have Visual Studio 2013.

I created a database project.

I added a CLR stored procedure to that project, and I want to call a WCF service from it.

Can anyone help me?

I want be able to change service address without changing my assembly, similar to what I can do in `web.config` with the `endpoint` section of my WCF client config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this after a lot of searching and spend very much time on this in VS 2014

1. Create `Database Project`  Called "CLR_Test"
2. Create `Library` For WCF Client  "CLR_Service_Client"
3. Add `Serivce Refrence` of wcf service to "CLR_Test" then add refrence of "CLR_Service_Client" into "CLR_Test"
   4.You must change DB Option to able run unsafe assemblyes with the below code

   `ALTER DATABASE SaleAutomation SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
   RECONFIGURE`
4. In the "CLR_Test" `Project Properties` in the `SQLCLR` tab set `Permission level` to `Unsafe` (another way is exist that after publish project you change its level from sql server management and another way is you add permission level to script of publish you can use each of them,
   but you must noticed that if you use from `project properties` only "CLR_Test" project automaticly create `Unsafe` and you must use other ways to set "CLR_Service_Client" `Unsafe` )
   [image]
   6.Run this Scripts to add Sqlserver be able to run wcf service

```sql
CREATE ASSEMBLY 
SMDiagnostics from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\SMDiagnostics.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY 
[System.Web] from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY 
[System.Messaging] from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Messaging.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
 GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY  
[System.IdentityModel] from
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY  
[System.IdentityModel.Selectors] from
'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\System.IdentityModel.Selectors.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY -- this will add service modal
[Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge] from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\Microsoft.Transactions.Bridge.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO

CREATE ASSEMBLY -- this will add service modal
[System.Runtime.Serialization] from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO
CREATE ASSEMBLY -- this will add service modal
[System.ServiceModel] from
'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation\System.ServiceModel.dll'
with permission_set = UNSAFE
GO
```

7. now you publish your project and run stored procedure and enjoy.

Comment: this is where I stopped.... because it don't work after this steps Could not load file or assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. Assembly in host store has a different signature than assembly in GAC. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131050) See Microsoft Knowledge Base article 949080 for more information.
and KB article don't help ether

Answer (score 2):

This is all moot since .Net v4.0, the System.ServiceModel is a mixed MSIL, meaning it using native code which will generate:

CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'System.ServiceModel' failed because assembly 'microsoft.visualbasic.activities.compiler' is malformed or not a pure .NET assembly. 
Unverifiable PE Header/native stub.
This would have been a wonderful elegant solution for what we wanted to do, but Microsoft again leaves us hanging on cliff

Answer (score 0):

I found new way for my problem
If you call your `wcf service` in service refrence as `Web Refrence` you must not have to do any thing

1. First add service refrence
   [image]
2. Second add Service as web reference 
   [image]
3. All is Done and continue to call service with method

Comment: This may be due to older version of SQL Server only uses .NET 2 and not .NET 4.  You didn't mention what version of SQL you were attempting.